# Strange boolean evaluation in GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to understand boolean expressions in GitHub actions. The manual gives the [following example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#literals) of literals of different types, including boolean as `${{ false }}` and `${{ true }}`.

Following their lead I use the [following step](https://github.com/travisdowns/gha-test/blob/8231125ef930b66aaec38561addabcd245a1a036/.github/workflows/build.yml#L25-L35) with an `env` section that sets `VARF` to false and `VART` to true and then in the `run` key has some test output:

```
  - name: Var test
    env:
      VARF: ${{ false }}
      VART: ${{ true }}
    run: |
      echo "VART=${{ env.VARF }}"
      echo "VART=${{ env.VART }}"
      echo "VARF && VART=${{ env.VARF && env.VART }}"
      echo "VARF || VART=${{ env.VARF || env.VART }}"
      echo "!VARF=${{ ! env.VARF }}"
      echo "!!VART=${{ !! env.VART }}"
```

The [output](https://github.com/travisdowns/gha-test/runs/3425012281?check_suite_focus=true#step:3:1) is as follows:

```
VART=false
VART=true
VARF && VART=true
VARF || VART=false
!VARF=false
!!VART=true
```

The plain output is as expected, showing `true` and `false`. The output of the `&&` and `||` operators is the opposite of expected, giving `false && true == true` and `false || true == false`. The output of `${{ ! env.VARF }}` is false when I'd expect true.

What's going on here? Possibly variables in the env context get coerced to strings, but that still doesn't explain all the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is completely valid and easy to understand if you know JavaScript (or Python, ...). You can test it in browser console in JavaScript:

```js
'false' && 'true' // "true"
'false' || 'true' // "false"
!'false' // false
!!'true' // true
```

---

If you are not familiar to JavaScript, here is the explanation:

1. Yes, variables in the env context are just strings.
2. Any non-empty string is considered truthy in logical operation. `!'false' == !true == false`. Also `!!` is often used to convert something to boolean in JavaScript.
3. Short-circuit evaluation. In short `and` and `or` return first part which determines the final value.

   For example in `'false' && 'true'`, `'false'` is evaluated to `true`, and the final value of `'false' && 'true'` is determined by `'true'`. So `'true'` is returned.

   In `'false' || 'true'`, `'false'` is evaluated to `true`, the final value is determined. So it returns `'false'`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes total sense. The `||` and `&&` results threw me, but given the short-circuit behavior along with the fact they are not really boolean operators but rather return the same type of objects as passed to them, it all makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

There is some inconsistency between the input context (dispatch_workflow vs workflow_call) and the way booleans are treated by GitHub Actions. I have a short write-up on this. Hope you find this helpful

[GitHub Actions: Passing Boolean input variables to reusable workflow_call](https://medium.com/@sohail.ra5/github-actions-passing-boolean-input-variables-to-reusable-workflow-call-42d39bf7342e?source=friends_link&sk=4b8a1d08f172674fc734aa6de701fec0)

Comment: What a mess....

Comment: While providing an external link can be good for reference, it's better to answer the question using the native stackoverflow authoring tools. External links may come and go and it's desired to put all the information for an answer in the content of the answer for permanency rather than depending on 3rd party resources being available.

Comment: The link is a great explanation, but @Nuvious is right: best to give a recap, since the link will die (or fall behind a pay wall) at some point.